# Update a single cell of Google Sheets using JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I've followed this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/js) and I am able to successfully get it working to "get" data from the spreadsheet, but now I would like to update a single cell using just the JavaScript API.  I'm trying to use this JS method:

```
    gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
      spreadsheetId: 'something',
      range: 'Sheet1!B2',
    })
```

But I'm not quite sure how to pass in the new cell value into the Request body.  I've tried my best to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) as a guide but I'm not quite sure how to use this.  I can't find any documentation around "gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update" JavaScript API.  I get 400 errors back from the API with anything I've tried.

Comment: A good nights rest did me some good; I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 13):

```
gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId: 'something',
    range: 'Sheet1!B2',
    valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
    values: [ ["123"] ]
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Hi,

I am getting error code 403, permission denied with the message: The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.
Can you please help??

Comment: @Tim this should be updated to replace "values" with "resource" as Curtis Chong has below.

Answer (score 7):

I think google updated their API because Tim's answer didn't work for me. Here is my structure:

```
let spreadsheetId = "idOfMySheet";
let range = "nameOfSheet!A1";
let valueInputOption = "RAW";
let myValue = 5;

let values = [[myValue]];
let resource = {
    values,
};
sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    spreadsheetId,
    range,
    valueInputOption,
    resource
}, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('%d cells updated.', result.updatedCells);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This [link](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)

For updating sheet values, authorization is required with non-read-only OAuth scope like `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`

and then

```js
 return gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
        "spreadsheetId": sid,
        "range": sheetName + "!A2:D",
        "includeValuesInResponse": "true",
        "responseDateTimeRenderOption": "FORMATTED_STRING",
        "responseValueRenderOption": "FORMATTED_VALUE",
        "valueInputOption": "USER_ENTERED",
        "resource": {
          "majorDimension": "ROWS",
          "range": sheetName + "!A2:D",
          "values": [['data1', 'data2', 'data3', 'data4']]
        }
      }).then(function(response) {
       console.log(response);
      
      }, function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
```

Comment: for single cell used '"range": sheetName+"!B1",'